# SQL charindex returns 0

Tags: sql-server, charindex

I am confused in using **charindex** operator in SQL server. When I concatenate the **car** field with commas I get the desired output but when I check again the index of 12 in the result, I get 0 . The field car is `INT` and I have also checked the 12 without single quotation.

```
select concat(',',car,',') as car from drivers where id=38
```

**output:** `,12,`

```
select CHARINDEX(concat(',',car,','),'12') as carindex from drivers where id=38
```

**output:** `0`

Comment: You've swapped the two arguments. It happens to me all the time as well; it seems much more logical to first have the expression, then the search argument, but that's just not how it goes. Of course `12` does not contain `,12,` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put an expression to find at the first place:

```
select CHARINDEX('12', CONCAT(',', @car,','), 0)
```

[As MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter is `start_location`, you may not have length of characters.

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017